# Using RTL with SQL statement in Oracle Apex SQL Commands

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

When trying to write WHERE CONTAINS in Oracle Apex SQL Commands:

```
  WHERE CONTAINS (CAR, 'السيارة البيضاء OR السيارة السوداء', 1) > 0;
```

Am getting the following error:

```
Error at line 26/33: ORA-00904: "السيارة البيضاء OR السيارة السوداء": invalid identifier
```

If not using RTL, it will look like below and it works:

```
 WHERE CONTAINS (CAR, 'WHITE CARE OR BLACK CAR', 1) > 0;
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   cars
WHERE  CONTAINS (CAR, 'السيارة البيضاء OR السيارة السوداء', 1) > 0;
```

*Note: this is in the format `WHERE CONTAINS(car, 'text1 OR text2', 1) > 0` however the RTL formatting makes it look malformed when it is not.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cars ( car ) AS
SELECT 'abc السيارة البيضاء def' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ghi السيارة السوداء jkl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mno pqr' FROM DUAL;

CREATE INDEX cars__car__textidx ON cars(car) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

Outputs:

> | CAR |
> | --- |
> | abc السيارة البيضاء def |
> | ghi السيارة السوداء jkl |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d30ede6df9b0a3a086068be99a9db638)*